# cannot modify array value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple php script that handles form data. In the form I have several checkboxes, and when those are checked, the form contains "on" as a value.

For the remainder of the script, I need to have the string "1" instead of "on", but I can't change it for some reason.

Here is the script:

```
$posted=$_POST;
foreach ($posted as $key=>$val) {
    if ($val == "on") {
        $posted[$key] = "1";
    }
}
// The $_POST parameters
echo 'The $_POST parameters:';
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

// The $posted parameters after conversion
echo 'The $posted parameters (after \'conversion\'):';
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($posted);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output:

```
The $_POST parameters:
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(6) "142892"
  ["help"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["vm"]=>
  string(2) "on"
}

The $posted parameters (after 'conversion'):

array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(6) "142892"
  ["help"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["vm"]=>
  string(2) "on"
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify $_POST variable.

Comment: Yes, I know. I do not try that. see script.

Comment: but he is already modifying $posted variable not the $_POST variable itself.

Comment: Create your own array $array= array(); and then insert your key and values. By the way you can use ternary conditional operator for that.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I beg to differ, given that I use `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);` *all the time*.

Comment: Have you tried printing the $_POST or $posted? As far as i remember you cannot pass a value for a checkbox. A checkbox exist or not exists, it doesn't have any value.

Comment: I'm with Niet the Dark Absol, you can modify the $_POST variable if you really want to.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol php://input returns raw input. You can change that.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain so what? I think Niet the Dark Absol's point was that he is modifying $_POST, not anything about php://input

Comment: i tried your code with adding `$_POST = array (
  "id"=> "142892",
  "help"=>"on",
  "vm"=> "on",
);` at the begining and it works as expected, result is `array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(6) "142892"
  ["help"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["vm"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}`

Comment: @RandolphCarter No, I am not.  I hope people are reading my question and not just the comments. :D

Comment: You shouldn't modify the array you are looping through. Create a new one with same keys and your "1" value.

This is a good question though. Are array values somehow locked whithin a foreach ?

Comment: @volk - care to explain why you think you shouldn't modify the array you are looping through?

Comment: @koljanep You are not ... *what*? (modifying $_POST? yes, I know, I've read the question)

Comment: Your problem can't be reproduced. It works [fine](http://3v4l.org/uBCYV).

Comment: @Stanyer I speak in more general way to treat arrays with foreach. I think changing values during a foreach is not safe from errors. You can end up with infinite loop, bad values, bad keys... When you don't know for sure what's in the array, it is best to create a new one and work on it. Not to mention it saves you from mosts of array rows checks.

Comment: @Volk I just think you're making a problem where there isn't one. You might feel it's safer but it doesn't really make a difference, if it did you wouldn't be able to prefix a variable with `&` to make it be passed by reference

Comment: @RandolphCarter ok do it that way, why are you fighting ?

Answer (score 3):

First the code you supplied does what you expect and modifies the 'posted' array correctly (PHP 5.3.18).

According to the PHP 'foreach' documentation, to modify the 'value' in the loop you need to use a 'reference' to the 'value' as follows:

As you are only interested in modifying all the 'on' values in the posted' array then the following code does that and is clear as to what is being changed.

```
$posted=$_POST;
foreach ($posted as &$val) { // note the 'reference' on $val
    if ($val == "on") {
        $val = "1";
    }
}
```

This does what you want without any extra variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
 $posted = array();
    $posted=$_POST;
    foreach ($posted as $key=>$val) {
        if ($val == "on") {
            $_POST[$key] = "1";
        }
    }
    var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use another array when you use a foreach loop

```
$posted = array();
$postArray = $_POST;
foreach ($postArray as $key=>$val) {
    if ($val == "on") {
        $posted[$key] = "1";
    }
    else {
        $posted[$key] = $val;
    }
}
var_dump($posted);
```

An array used in a foreach loop is not editable and it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
$posted = array();
$posted=$_POST;
foreach ($posted as $key=>$val) {
    if ($val == "on") {
        $posted[$key] = "1";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the same code that is used by koljanep in his question.